# How to ensure that JS anonymous objects continue to map onto POCO ViewModels

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

We have an ASP.NET MVC application that extensively uses AJAX calls.

These AJAX calls send data to our controller method - this controller method requires an argument which is a simple POCO ViewModel class.

In our JavaScript we create an anonymous object whose properties map onto the properties of our ViewModel, and the MVC framework handles all the routing so that in the controller method we get our ViewModel with all the properties.

All well and good.

What we want to do is to put in place a robust way to ensure that the JavaScript anonymous class and the ViewModel class remain in-synch - if a developer changes one then they change the other.  We can of course put in comments in both files to say "change one, change the other", and a threat of a severe beating for the developer who fails to keep these in synch, but even with code reviews this is an area that may be missed.

It would be great to have some kind of automated unit test that could check for this, but I'm not aware how to achieve this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Griff

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript library called knockoutjs and it is used exactly for what you are trying to achieve.  It seems like you are trying to use the MVVM pattern with the ASP.NET MVC framework.  With any MVVM pattern, it's a common problem to keep your viewmodel in sync with the view.  KnockoutJS allows you to created javascript viewmodels client-side that bind directly to the view.  The viewmodels get updated when the view is updated and the view is updated when the viewmodel is updated.  KnockoutJS uses a common pattern called the Observer pattern to acheive this.  KnockoutJS also provides a mapping plug in so the viewmodels can receive server-side viewmodels in JSON format and update itself, thus updating the view.  This is the functionality that you are looking for.  The library and the mapping plugin can be found on their website, www.knockoutjs.com.  FYI...it is a producation level library.  They also have great documentation and examples.  I hope this helps.  don't re-invent the wheel.